# How to set the icon size of jqWidgets tree?

Tags: jquery, jqwidget, jqxwidgets

I am creating a jqWidget tree using the , I aded my own icons to expand and collapse of tree items. The default size of the tree icon is 16px I want to change it to 25px, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The toggleIndicatorSize property defines the Size of the expand/collapse icons.